# Problem setting Icon image source in Context Menu from code behind

Tags: silverlight, image, silverlight-4.0, contextmenu

I have a DataGrid in a UserControl and I have added a ContextMenu to the DataGrid.

The XAML is as follows:

```
<sdk:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=GridSource}">
    <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=OneWay}" Header="Name"/>
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Number, Mode=OneWay}" Header="Number"/>
    </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
    <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
        <toolkit:ContextMenu Opened="ContextMenu_Opened">
            <toolkit:MenuItem IsEnabled="False">
                <toolkit:MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Image x:Name="menuIcon"/> 
                </toolkit:MenuItem.Icon>
            </toolkit:MenuItem>
            <toolkit:Separator />
            <toolkit:MenuItem Header="View Agent Route" Click="AgentRoute_Click"/>
            <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Live Track" Click="LiveTrack_Click"/>
        </toolkit:ContextMenu>
    </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
</sdk:DataGrid>
```

If I set the source of the menuIcon Image in XAML using

```
<Image x:Name="menuIcon" Source="../../Assets/Images/user_green.png"/>
```

Then the icon is rendered fine but if I try to set it in the ContextMenu_Opened event handler using:

```
private void ContextMenu_Opened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  menuIcon.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("../../Assets/Images/user_green.png", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Nothing shows up, I don't get an error or anything it just doesn't show.  I've used the same method to set an ImageSource (using the same actual *.png files) elsewhere in my application, any ideas what's happening here?

Is this due to it being a ContextMenu?  On a grid?  I can't figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this one working by using a [ImageSourceConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagesourceconverter.aspx) within the contextmenu_opened event.

```
private void ContextMenu_Opened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  ImageSourceConverter converter = new ImageSourceConverter();
  menuIcon.Source = (ImageSource)converter.ConvertFromString("../../Assets/Images/user_green.png");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using:-

```
 new Uri("/Assets/Images/user_green.png", UriKind.Relative")
```

As general rule I would avoid ".." parent paths if at all possible, they only cause headaches.  You know that there is a Assets folder at the root of the Xap so start with "/Assets" and go from there.

Comment: Tried that but it's still not working.  Can you think of any reason why it works when set through XAML but not through code behind?

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass in an Image.  This worked for me:

```
var mus = new MenuItem {
Header = "Unicorns...",
Icon = new Image {
 Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/myApp;component/img/unicorns.png",UriKind.Relative))
}
};
```